# List of Points +Constructor and Method problems

Tags: java, arraylist

So for this project I wish to input an array containing a number of points. (no specific number). I am confused on how I should approach the methods and constructor because some of the methods call for changes such as grabbing the average of the X or Y values. Am I approaching this project in the right way? Should I be using a clone of the point list, or an array list or what... (note I am only showing part of the PolygonImpl class as an example, they all function similarly) The class point contains :

```
public class Point {

private double x;
private double y;

public Point(double x, double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public double getX() {
    return x;
}

public double getY() {
    return y;
}

public Point translate(double dx, double dy) {
    return new Point(x+dx, y+dy);
}

public double distanceTo(Point p) {
    return Math.sqrt((p.x - x)*(p.x -x) + (p.y-y)*(p.y-y));
}
```

}

```
public class PolygonImpl implements Polygon {

private double xSum=0;
private double ySum=0;
private ArrayList<Point> points;
private Point[] pList;
private Point a;

PolygonImpl(Point[] pList) {

    this.pList = pList.clone();
    points = new ArrayList<Point>();

    for (int index = 0; index < pList.length; index++) {
           points.add(pList[index]);
       xSum += pList[index].getX();
       ySum += pList[index].getY();


    }
}



public Point getVertexAverage() {
     double xSum = 0;
     ArrayList<Point> vlist = new ArrayList<Point> ();
     double ySum = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < vlist.size(); index++) {
         xSum = xSum + vlist.get(index).getX();
         ySum = ySum + vlist.get(index).getY();
        }

    return new Point(xSum/getNumSides(), ySum/getNumSides());
}

public int getNumSides() {
    return pList.length;
}

public void move(Point c) {
    Point newCentroid = new Point(a.getX()+ c.getX(), a.getY() +c.getY());


}

public void scale(double factor) {

 ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point> ();

    for (int index = 0; index < pList.length; index++) {
        { double x = pList[index].getX() *factor;
          double y = pList[index].getY() * factor;
          Point a = new Point(x,y);
            points.add(index,a);

        }
    }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I don't think you need the extra List objects; they are redundant.
Here is the code just using the pList array.

```
public class PolygonImpl implements Polygon {

private double xSum=0;
private double ySum=0;
private Point[] pList;
private Point a;

    PolygonImpl(Point[] pList) {

        this.pList = pList.clone();

        for (int index = 0; index < pList.length; index++) {
           xSum += pList[index].getX();
           ySum += pList[index].getY();
        }
    }



    public Point getVertexAverage() {
         double xSum = 0;
         double ySum = 0;
        for (int index = 0; index < pList.length; index++) {
             xSum = xSum + pList[index].getX();
             ySum = ySum + pList[index].getY();
            }

        return new Point(xSum/getNumSides(), ySum/getNumSides());
    }

    public int getNumSides() {
        return pList.length;
    }

    public void move(Point c) {
        Point newCentroid = new Point(a.getX()+ c.getX(), a.getY() +c.getY());


    }

    public void scale(double factor) {
        for (int index = 0; index < pList.length; index++)
        {
            double x = pList[index].getX() *factor;
            double y = pList[index].getY() * factor;
            Point a = new Point(x,y);
            pList[index] = a;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Would using the pList for the scale() method change it entirely? I was worried that if I did not use another object it would negatively impact the rest of my class

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, exactly, by "change it entirely" or "negatively impact".  The code above will:  iterate through each point in pList;  create a new Point object that is scaled by the factor; finally, replace the current point with the new point.  Okay, I see that this scale method forgot to update the xSum and ySum.  You can do that just by multiplying them by the factor, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three things here that need pointing out.

The first is the difference between "clone" and "copy."  .clone is a shallow copy; that means if you change the clone, you also change the original.

The second is regarding your use of collections.  Since a polygon is a collection of points, either an array or an ArrayList would be approriate, but there is no point in using bother, or, if there is, think long and hard about whether it's a good point, and then explain in the inline documentation why it matters, else it will come back to bite you in the form of using one when you mean the other.

Third is scope.  Your polygon class has instance variables (xSum and ySum) that are occluded by variables with the same name in getVertexAverage.  The way they are used in getVertexAverage is appropriate in itself; the instance variables are only useful if you mean to cache the sums, which becomes more questionable, because every operation that changes a point invalidates the instance values.

Instance values are for storing data about an object (in this case, points are reasonable); instance methods are for operating on that data at a given state (in this case, the average).

Keeping this in mind, you can now understand how the move method isn't finished :)

Comment: If I used clone in my constructor, how would I use it properly in the following methods? I don't understand much of the clone() operation.

Comment: If you don't care that you're making a shallow copy, then you're using clone correctly.  This object would benefit from a "sum" method, since you are doing that it more than one place.